# The Fitting subgroup centralizes minimal normal subgroups in finite groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group:
If $N$ is a minimal normal subgroup of $G$, then $F(G) \leq C_G(N)$.

Here $C_G(N)$ denotes the centralizer of $N$ in $G$, and
$F(G)$ denotes the Fitting subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $N$ is abelian, then $N \leq F$ and $[F,N] < N$ is still normal, so $[F,N]=1$ as claimed. If $N$ is non-abelian, then $[F,N] \leq F \cap N = 1$ as claimed.

You may try to prove sort of a converse: $F(G)$ is the intersection of the centralizers, not just of the minimal normal subgroups, but of all $K/L$ where $K$ is a minimal normal subgroup of $G/L$.

Comment: Why  [F,N]≤F∩N=1........ F intersection of N =1 (WHY)?

Comment: If $N$ is nonabelian, then it is not nilpotent, so $N \not\leq F$. So, $F \cap N < N$ and $N$ is minimal normal. Since $F \cap N$ is normal too, the only possibility is $F \cap N = 1$.

Comment: Are u sure    "  
If N is nonabelian, then it is not nilpotent" ?

Comment: Yes, because $N$ is a minimal normal subgroup, but $[N,N]$ is another normal subgroup. If it is $1$, then $N$ is abelian. If not, then $[N,N]=N$ and $N$ is not nilpotent.

Comment: Tank you. parden me "if i  have question can i mail you ?"

Comment: This website is better. During the school year I have 600 students, so it is difficult to keep track of emails.

Comment: Hi, Parden me i have just one question                              if N is abelian, [F,N]=N not can true Why ?

Comment: If N is abelian, then N ≤ F. F is a nilpotent group and nilpotent groups have a nice property: if X is a non-identity normal subgroup of F, then [F,X] < X. This is called “nilpotent action”. Proof: Assume by way of contradiction that [F,X] = X. Then [F,[F,X]] = [F,X] = X, so X = [F,[F,....,[F,X]...]] ≤ [F,[F,....,[F,F]..]] = 1 (if there are enough [F, ...).

Comment: Completly i got it. tank you tank you. I wish you could see it up close.