# $G$ soluble and Unique minimal normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a soluble group and $N$ is only minimal normal subgroup of $G$.
Is this  $N=C‎_{G}‎(N)$ true?

Comment: Have you considered groups of order 4?

Comment: No. $G$ is finite solvable group

Comment: M.Mazoo, what @DerekHolt is telling you, look for a counterexample among groups of order $4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [The Fitting subgroup centralizes minimal normal subgroups in finite groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414144/the-fitting-subgroup-centralizes-minimal-normal-subgroups-in-finite-groups) we know this is generally wrong, since $C_G(N) \geq \operatorname{Fit}(N)$.

In particular, every non-simple $p$-group gives a counterexample, since a minimal normal subgroup is contained in the center, and so its centralizer is the whole group. For example, if $N=2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \unlhd G = \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, then $N$ is minimal normal but $C_G(N)=G$ is bigger than $N$.

Comment: Right. If we assume Group is finite. Is true ?

Comment: No, it is not true. $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is finite.